# How to know if a function encloses a finite region of space?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, geometry

So my question is: if we have a function f(x, y), how do we know if the curve f(x, y)=0 encloses a finite region or not. As an example, the curve $x^2+y^2-1=0$ encloses a finite region, while the curve $x^2-y^2-1=0$ doesn't.

Comment: My first guess is to reformulate the equation in polar coordinates and then see if you can find a radius $R$ such that for all other radii $r>R$, the equation admits no solutions.  This is super vague though so it's not quite an answer.

Comment: Maybe the equivalent without reformulation would be finding X and Y such that for any |x| > X and |y| > Y the equation has no solutions. Or alternatively the equation doesn't change its sign? It really is super vague tho yeah

Comment: You should use the adjective "bounded" instead of "finite" for such a region.

Comment: One more word about exact words : $f(x,y)$ is not an equation : you should write $f(x,y)=0$. If you want to progress in mathematics, take care to what you write.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following result from geometric analysis due to [Matthew Grayson (1987)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature_flow#Convergence_theorems):

> Let $g:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth embedding, then the mean curvature flow with initial data $g$ eventually consists exclusively of embeddings with strictly positive curvature.

Mean curvature flow is the process of distorting an embedded smooth curve (or more generally embedded smooth manifold) at every point in the direction of its mean curvature vector. What this says is that if $g$ defines a curve defining a bounded region, then that curve will deform into a circle. Moreover this circle will shrink to a single point in finite time.
[image]

Image: [David Eppstein (CC0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve-shortening_flow#/media/File:Convex_curve_shortening.png)

This if you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ whose level set is a disjoint union of smoothly embedded curves, you can independently perform mean curvature flow on each component of $f(x,y)=0$. If each component bounds a finite region, then in finite time this will produce a set of points. Thus the set of such functions $f$ is recursively enumerable.

(*Remark:* in fact it is the case that if two components of $f(x,y)=0$ are nested embeddings of $\mathbb{S}^1$, then performing mean curvature flow on both simultaneously, the two curves will not intersect at any point (until after the inner curve has shrunk to a point).

This doesn't completely answer your question, but hopefully it is somewhat useful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't call a region of $\mathbb{R}^2$ finite unless its cardinal is finite. What you are trying to say it is that the region is bounded (that is, that there is some $D(x_0,r)$ such that the region is inside the disck)

Although this is not a very concrete question, I guess that the best I can offer you is the [Jordan Curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). It states that if you have a jordan curve $C$ (a simple closed curve) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ consists of exactly two connected components, one of the components is bounded (called the interior) and the other is unbounded (called the exterior). So every Jordan Curve 'Encloses a finite region of the space'.

In your examples $x^2+y^2-1=0$ is a circumference, which is a jordan curve and so the theorem holds. On the other hand $x^2-y^2-1=0$ is not a jordan curve because it is not a closed curve.